# ASP.NET Web API, Simple/Custom Membership, AngularJS, and Petapoco

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I'm working on a simple AngularJS Web application.

I want to implement authentication using login and password only once.

All the Web API security examples I could find are sending username and password for every single request and makes use of Entity Framework.

I want to have a login page, authenticate the user once and let them use the app.

I want to use PetaPoco since i find Entity Framework to be too complicated (i will have to learn Linq). But the simpleMembership provider examples uses Entity Framework). Even the MVC4 internet application uses Entity Framework.

any thoughts/samples?

Comment: My guess is the examples you're seeing are based on a truly RESTful interface where there is no state stored.  This allows for a site to be scaled across servers since each request can be handled independently.  I'm not sure about how you handle sessions in ASP but in PHP this would be the alternative to a truly stateless server setup.  In this case a token is stored on the client in a cookie and should eventually be expired by the server (and client eventually).

Comment: is the REST service hosted in the same domain of your application?

Comment: @Vivek Login and password should never be saved on client side due to security. Only a token should be saved on client side in the localstorage and sessionstorage(IE8+). With every request to the server you send the token + the data.

Answer (score 0):

I just have 2 options at the top of my head right now:

1. If the service is hosted in the same domain you can use an auth cookie and you can make a custom auth provider or a custom authorization filter that will handle all the logic for the authorization there and use the ORM that you want and decorate the methods you want to protect something like 1.[Authorize(Roles="manager")]
2. there's another way you can do it you can implement HMAC you can generate it in your login method then you can attach the HMAC signature to the request and validate that request, you need to save that computed sigature if the signature computed by the server matches the on the message it means that the message is authorized.

I know that this is more a matter of preferences but I dont like the idea of sending a login and password everytimr you'll need something from you REST service.

you can take a look to [this article](http://www.piotrwalat.net/hmac-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/) that seems very nice

you may have to consider into your app a way to [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery Attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201748.aspx)

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We have been using the same stack as you have mentioned in your question. ASP.Net MVC, Web API, PetaPoco. We use the [ASP.Net Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) with its default configuration.

Once the user is authenticated within the ASP.Net MVC application, request to webapi do not require passing in any specific credentials. Since the underlying framework is ASP.Net the FormAuthenticationModule takes care of Authentication part seamlessly.

Regarding you problem with EF. I don't consider that a problem because you are not interacting with EF. The library is and you are just a consumer of the library. It may add dependency on EF but that does not effect you implementation, you are free to use any data access library you want. The usage of EF has been abstract.